# How to control stdin echo in C++?

Tags: c++, io

In Linux, I can use tcsetattr, but I want to write a portable C++ program that can turn echo of cin on and off (for entering a password). Is there something in std::io* that supports this?

Comment: Portable C++ has no notion of a "terminal" or an "echo". There is no portable echo.

Comment: std::cin doesn't do the echo, your terminal does that. It is out of c++'s control.

Comment: `getch` in `<conio.h>` will do the trick, it handle read of a single byte(without echo and no need of enter), but it is c, not c++. and also you'll need to handle backspaces & enter presses, and if you really want to go further, also the arrow keys, home & end...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no portable way to disable console echo, so you have to use OS specific API. You can use preprocessor to write portable program, but you would have to write separate code for supported OS and wrap it into `#ifdef` condition. Another solution would be to use portable library if such one exists, that would do this under the hood for you.

Comment: Perhaps you might find some C++ framework libraries to help you, like (maybe) [poco](http://pocoproject.org/). I don't know if it wraps the desired functionality.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. C/C++'s IO libraries are based around the "stream" model, where input comes from some random source of characters (generally the console) and output is similarly sent to some random character target. In a sense, it isn't C/C++ doing the echoing at all -- it's the console system -- so there's no way for it to control whether the echoing occurs.